# Multiple browser execution of sahi scripts at the same time

Tags: ant, sahi

I want to run sahi script via ant integration in different browser at the same time. I tried to specify browser field as "chrome+firefox" in the build.xml. but m getting an error:

Sahi tests failed on browser chrome+firefox!

Can someone help me out????

Comment: Which version of Sahi are you running? Is it pro or open source? Where did you generate your ant file from? Did you write it yourself or used it from somewhere? Check this link meanwhile http://sahipro.com/docs/using-sahi/playback-desktop.html#Playback via ANT
You need to actually create three different targets for three browsers

Comment: sahi pro i am using. By the way thanks for your help. just some time before got the solution.